# Div abaixo de outra - menu fixo

Tags: html, css

Estou criando um menu fixo e estou com problema.

Quando coloco o position fixed na div do menu a div que estava abaixo (conteudo) "sobe", assim parte do conteúdo fica escondido na div do menu.

Creio que não é correto eu colocar margin-top nessa div conteúdo.

Segue o exemplo:

```
  <!-- menu fixo !-->
  <div style="position:fixed; width:100%; z-index:999; background-color:#000;top:0; left:0">
    <p> Seja bem vindo </p>
  </div>

  <!-- conteudo !-->
  <div>
      <h1> Conteudo </h1>
  </div>
```

Comment: Você pode usar margin-top ou padding-top. Não há problema algum nisso.

Comment: Como o @hugocsl disse na resposta, colocar no body tb é uma solução.

Comment: No meu caso não da certo pelo motivo da div conteúdo ser dinâmica. Geralmente é uma foto abaixo do menu, e não é sempre a mesma foto. Logo, o tamanho vai variar, e com o margin-top dependendo da img, vai cortar parte. Entende?

Comment: Não entendi. O espaço abaixo do menu fixo deveria ter uma altura constante, que vc compensa com margin-top ou padding-top para que a div não fique por baixo do menu. Ou então vc está carregando essas imagens de baixo pra cima rs.

Comment: Todo conteúdo que se insere na página, a orientação é de cima pra baixo, logo não tem como nada ficar por baixo do menu.

Comment: Sim, sei disso! Colocando o padding-top resolveu meu problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vc pode colocar um `padding-top` no próprio `body`, *que é o jeito que o Bootstrap por exemplo recomenda*. [fonte](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#navbar-fixed-top)

```
body { padding-top: 70px; }
```

**OBS:** o valor do padding deve ser proporcional a altura do menu. Veja o exemplo para entender melhor

```css
body {
    padding-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
    <!-- menu fixo !-->
  <div style="position:fixed; width:100%; z-index:999; background-color:#000;top:0; left:0; color: #fff;">
    <p> Seja bem vindo </p>
  </div>

  <!-- conteudo !-->
  <div>
      <h1> Conteudo </h1>
  </div>
```